# Realizar busqueda con llave primaria y foranea

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo las siguientes instrucciones para crear 2 tablas en oracle, no conozco mucho de sql aun pero quiero hacer una consulta donde se usen ambas llaves, primaria y foranea, digamos que el usuario 1 tiene 3 compras, de las cuales cada una tiene un codigo, quiero hacer algun comando en sql que si yo lo uso me muestre todas los codigos relacionados a ese usuario con el cod_user

```
create table usuarios(
cod_user int not null,
name varchar(20),
constraint pk_usuarios
primary key (cod_user));

create table productos(
cod_prod int not null,
cod_user int not null,
brand varchar(20),
value number,
CONSTRAINT pk_productos 
PRIMARY KEY (cod_prod),
CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios 
FOREIGN KEY (cod_user)
REFERENCES usuarios(cod_user));
```

Comment: Has intentado hacer algo?.

Comment: O sea, queres hacer un select? te recomendaria que empezaras leyendo un manual de sql, ya que lo que estas pidiendo en los basico.

Comment: Puedes agregar alguna sentencia SQL que ya tengas? según entiendo tu pregunta lo resuelves con una sentencia  SELECT sencilla.

Comment: es que hasta ahora inicie en sql, se hacer el select comun y corriente, como este select * from usuarios where cod_user=1, pero no se como hacer la busqueda que yo quiero

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de consulta que estás intentando hacer tiene 2 opciones:

1) Usando una sintaxis ya un poco anticuada, algo así como

```
SELECT <columna deseada>
FROM <TABLA_PRINCIPAL> [alias1], <TABLA_SECUNDARIA> [alias2]
WHERE alias1.<clave_primaria> = alias2.<clave_foranea>
AND <columna_filtro> = :valor_deseado;
```

2) Usando la sintaxis **JOIN**

```
SELECT <columna deseada>
FROM <TABLA_PRINCIPAL> [alias1] 
JOIN <TABLA_SECUNDARIA> [alias2]
ON alias1.<clave_primaria> = alias2.<clave_foranea>
WHERE <columna_filtro> = :valor_deseado;
```

Eso traducido a tu problema sería algo así como:

```
SELECT cod_prod 
FROM usuarios usu 
JOIN productos pro
ON usu.cod_user = pro.cod_user 
WHERE usu.cod_user = :[valor a buscar];
```

Comment: no se si a usted le sirve correctamente, en mi caso cuando pego esa lineas en  el sql developer me muestra un error y cambie el valor a buscar haber si se arreglaba pero nada

Comment: Difiero en afirmar que es anticuada usar la sintáxis de hacer los joins en la cláusula WHERE. Es más un asunto de gusto ya que en cualquier caso el plan de ejecución es exactamente el mismo.
veáse: [https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-joins]

Comment: @Jose cual mensaje de error te da? Debes ser más explicito para poder ayudarte

Comment: @alvalongo sí, lo anticuada es secundaria. De hecho es mi favorita, siempre me parece más legible. Es seguro para mi usar esa sintaxis

Comment: @PatricioBonilla, estoy de acuerdo, se me facilita mucho más usar la notación non-ANSI de Oracle: uso alias simples para las tablas (letras a, b, c) y en el WHERE voy construyendo los joins recorriendo las tablas de arriba hacia abajo (como se ven en el FROM), tal que el lado izquierdo es la tabla con la letra más baja y el lado derecho es una tabla posterior.

Comment: @PatricioBonilla al pasar las 5 lineas al sql developer me muestra un error de sintaxis, el mensaje es asi, "Error de sintaxis. Reglas parcialmente reconocidas(diagrama de ferrocarril)" y al ejecutar esas mismas 5 lineas me muestra lo siguiente en consola,       ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 23, columna: 10

Comment: @Jose al parecer está ejecutando otras lineas. **Error en la línea 23...** no debería ser correcto si solo ejecutas las 5 lineas de la consulta. Recuerda que debe haber la opción de solo ejecutar la selección (las 5 lineas de la instrucción _SELECT_) en el editor.

Comment: @PatricioBonilla es que antes de la linea 23 tengo unos comandos de select, insert y delete pero estan funcionando correctamente, intente dejar la hoja en blanco y pegar las 5 lineas que me envio usted, y nada, seguia apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Cuando mencionas las 5 lineas son estas? 

`SELECT cod_prod 
FROM usuarios usu 
JOIN productos pro
ON usu.cod_user = pro.cod_user 
WHERE usu.cod_user = :[valor a buscar];`